# Multi-Camera streaming using Mathematica

Tags: dynamic, image-processing

I am attempting to capture dynamic streams from multiple usb webcams using only mathematica. Using `ImageCapture["Device" -> $ImagingDevices[[x]]`, I've tried to open multiple instances of *Mathematica* using ImageCapture on different devices for the different instances. No Luck :( Is this too complex a task for *Mathematica* alone?)

[Wolfram Community related question link](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/251849)

Comment: Perhaps you should also post this on community.wolfram.com - sound like a WRI job to answer.